# Pull Json data from json file mentioned as an entry in other json file through c#

Tags: c#, json

I have two related classes like the following

```
     public class college
     {

         public string Name{get;set}
         public int Id{get;set;}
         public domain MyDomain{get;set;}
     }  


      public class domain
      {
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public string TypeOfCourse{get;set;}

      }
```

and I have a json file called CollegeConfig.json and inside this file here is the json data

```
    {
         "currentVersion": 1,
         "college": [
         {
            "name": "somename",
            "id": "10",
            "domain":null
         }
      ]
    }
```

and there is a separate json file for object domain called domain.json. I'm stuck at  domain being null in CollegeConfig.json and having everything mentioned in terms of json data in  domain.json.
How can I get all the json data from inside domain.json file by just by looping through (I already looped through college class and reached MyDomain property which is null using c#) 
college class and getting a MyDomain property inside of it and then populating that MyDomain property from collegeconfig.json pulling all json data from domain.json.

In other words what should be the replacement value for  "domain":null in collegeconfig.json file so that it can pull all the json data from domain.json file itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should not separate the domain.json and collegeconfig.json files in this case, the data is coupled. If you want to do something like that, you'll have to have some code logic to combine the data (deserialize the collegeconfig.json, and loop over the entities adding the deserialized domain.json.

Code would be something like this:

```
public static college CombineJSON(string collegePath, string domainPath){
    var college = JSON.Deserialize<college>(collegePath);
    var domain = JSON.Deserialize<domain>(domainPath);
    college.domain = domain;
    return college;
}
```

Comment: @Micthell I have been instructed to do that way only .i.e separating 2 config files, will have to do that way only. Anyways the thing you have suggested I can give it a shot.